# One IP camera playing, one isn't. Codec incompatibility?

Tags: codec, h.264, media-player, ip-camera, video-codecs

I am new to video codecs and would like to understand my problem better.

I am using Siemens camera display in TIA V17 to display the RTSP streams of some IP cameras...

- IP camera A: Supports H264 but does not play, only shows a black screen.
- IP camera B: Runs on it just fine.

What could cause this problem? I have tried different resolutions and framerates on camera A and they both work in VLC. I am currently transcoding them to get around this but it is introducing some unwanted delays. Here is the `ffprobe -show_streams` output:

camera A:

```
Metadata:
    title           : 11
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.080000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 640x480, 12.50 fps, 12.50 tbr, 90k tbn
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=Main
codec_type=video
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=640
height=480
coded_width=640
coded_height=480
closed_captions=0
film_grain=0
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
display_aspect_ratio=N/A
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=51
color_range=tv
color_space=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
chroma_location=left
field_order=progressive
refs=1
is_avc=false
nal_length_size=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=25/2
avg_frame_rate=25/2
time_base=1/90000
start_pts=7200
start_time=0.080000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
extradata_size=53
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
DISPOSITION:captions=0
DISPOSITION:descriptions=0
DISPOSITION:metadata=0
DISPOSITION:dependent=0
DISPOSITION:still_image=0
[/STREAM]
```

camera B:

```
Metadata:
    title           : Session streamed with GStreamer
    comment         : rtsp-server
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.039989, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=Main
codec_type=video
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=1280
height=720
coded_width=1280
coded_height=720
closed_captions=0
film_grain=0
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuvj420p
level=41
color_range=pc
color_space=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
chroma_location=center
field_order=progressive
refs=1
is_avc=false
nal_length_size=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=25/1
avg_frame_rate=25/1
time_base=1/90000
start_pts=3599
start_time=0.039989
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
extradata_size=31
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
DISPOSITION:captions=0
DISPOSITION:descriptions=0
DISPOSITION:metadata=0
DISPOSITION:dependent=0
DISPOSITION:still_image=0
[/STREAM]
```